# Join variables in twig

Tags: theming

I want to join two variables in twig in the *user.html.twig*

```
{{ content.field_firstname }} {{ content.field_lastname }}
```

How can i output them on the same line and add a space between them using twig ?

Everytime i try, they show on two different lines ? and i don't want to use css just for this.

Is there any better way to do this ? Many thanks

Comment: Fields are wrapped in divs, divs have a block display by default. Using CSS is the easier solution, the alternative is overwriting templates for individual fields to remove the wrappers

Answer (score 5):

{% set full_name = [content.field_firstname ~ ' ' ~ content.field_lastname] %}

**Note: We use ~ in twig to concatenate two or more strings instead of "+"**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result that i get when i output {{ full_name }} is not the first name and last name but Array Array

Comment: Hope you are using the right variables.

Comment: Yes i am, when i output them indivisually they do work :S

Comment: I am not sure what kind of problem you are facing can you share your code. is it drupal8?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to dig a little deeper depending on the field type. If you `{{ kint(content) }}` in the template, you should be able to dig down to the actual value.

You might be looking for one of the following:

`{% set full_name = content.field_firstname.value ~ ' ' ~ content.field_lastname.value %}`

`{% set full_name = content.field_firstname.0['#markup'] ~ ' ' ~ content.field_lastname.0['#markup'] %}`

Or something similar.

Without seeing your code/kint output, it's hard to say. But that should get you going in the right direction.